# Fixing a broken dpkg and apt package manger

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, dpkg

I am working VM which I haven't administered in the past and it is in a bad state (but I need to rescue it). I am not a linux expert but in the past 5 years I have been able to fix problems by using google. After a complete day yesterday I dunno what else to do then asking dumb questions by just stating my problem.

- The system won't do a regular boot (I can however open a rescue root shell in which I can mount the file system and enable networking to some degree (I can reach outside networks but I cannot open port 22 or start an ssh deamon - I can however start apache and open port 80)
- I cannot install or remove software since dpkg always complains about old linux header images (I think a former administrator has deleted manually linux headers from the boot partition to make space.)
- Now each time I try to do apt-get install or remove or upgrade or whatever it complains that there where too many errors in dkpg and especially there where errors with some old linux images (which are not present on my boot partition) and it aborts. It also complains of not finding files (related to the old linux headers)
- I found one instruction that suggested to reinstall grub2 which I followed through. I think removing worked but installing broke in the same way as not other software can be installed. I am pretty confident the next time I wan't to restart the machine I will not even be able to enter a rescue system because grub2 seems to be uninstalled.
- I cannot do something like `apt-get install linux-image-generic`

I understand that this post does not even bare a proper question but I don't even know how to formulate one. There seem to be so many things broken that obviously I kind of lost track of where to start.

**edit**

output of `dpkg --get-selections` : http://pastebin.com/CRFaaJ7m

output of `apt-get install linux-generic`: http://pastebin.com/7t20Bavu

output of `dpgk --configure -a`: http://pastebin.com/Hpmch9dM

also I think the output might be interesting (especially starting at line 484): http://pastebin.com/uUi86FtT

Comment: So you can reach Internet from it, in recovery mode or just LAN? If you can mount extern USB disk, save the output of `apt-get install linux-image-generic`  and `dpkg --get-selections` and add both to the question, so we know its current state.

Comment: added the output via pastbin. but as sated I could only add useful output of dpkg. thanks anyway

Comment: Try with `apt-get -s -yy install linux-generic 2>&1 | tee output.txt` of you can get the output

Comment: logging in from a linux machine I could use moste keys so I have changed the past bin link: http://pastebin.com/7t20Bavu thanks (:

Comment: You have two issues (1) the two deleted kernel files (one to remove package, one half installed) and (2) dbus can't install due to post script. I want to confirm that you have some kernels left in the system. Please. add output of `ls -l /boot/vmlinuz* /boot/initrd*`

Comment: thanks for making sure images exist in boot. I checked this before but you can see the output of the two commands at http://imgur.com/a/BIGuy

Answer (score 3):

Could see only one old kernel from `dpkg` status, but I'm not sure if it really on the disk.

Anyway:

1. Make a backup of the DPKG status file

   ```
   cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.backup0
   ```
2. Clear those manually removed kernels from the DPKG status

   Check which line is the package entry

   ```
   grep -n linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```

   Open status for edit (change `xxxxx` with the line number)

   ```
   nano +xxxxx /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```

   Change its status to `deinstall` as this example

   ```
   Package: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic
   Status: install ok installed
   ```

   to

   ```
   Package: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic
   Status: deinstall ok config-files
   ```

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit
3. Make the previous step for the following packages

   ```
   linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic
   linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic
   linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic
   ```
4. Modify DBus post -install script to skip errors

   ```
   nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/dbus.postinst
   ```

   and comment `set -e` → `#set -e` (around line # 5)
5. Continue previous installation

   ```
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```
6. Fix dependencies

   ```
   apt -f install
   ```

Comment: I think I understand where you trying to go but already the first command says: `dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic which isn't installed` I read somehere I could just touch these files in boot so that dpkg could do some removal

Comment: as you can see here: http://imgur.com/a/Ia8nP the entry we were looking for do not exist in `/var/lib/dpkg/status` touching these files would mean touching them on the boot partition? could I also just append entries in the status file with the linux images and `status: deinstall ok config-files` or is that a bad idea since I am missing all the dependencies?

Comment: sorry your suggestion unfortunately didn't work. i changed the lines but allready `dpkg --configure -a` produced a similar output with many errors as before. I then tried `apt -g install` which said it would fix 89 half installed packages but after 2 percent i just got a screen full of `No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alread E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` I don't find a file in `/var/crash/` so I can't attach the output :(

Comment: @RenePickhardt, could you rerun `apt-get -yy -f install 2>&1 | tee output.txt` . To find the new show-stopper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49257/discussion-between-user-dz-and-rene-pickhardt).