# How to remove or purge a kernel package manually to resolve a stuck APT/DPKG installation?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I have faced lately some cases where the asker had a APT removal operation stuck due some kernel script errors.

Sometimes is easy to fix the root cause.

- Like `touch`ing the few missing files
- Removing bad config

  like: residue `/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/zz-flash-touch-initrd`
  [Boot: "Couldn't find data partition. Spawning adbd"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853484/boot-couldnt-find-data-partition-spawning-adbd) 
  [Installed ubuntu-touch package to test Unity8, computer won't start because it can't find data partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688663/installed-ubuntu-touch-package-to-test-unity8-computer-wont-start-because-it-c) 
  like: empty `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd`
  [Ubuntu 16.04 broken kernel packages won't let me install or remove anything with apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850101/ubuntu-16-04-broken-kernel-packages-wont-let-me-install-or-remove-anything-with)

But in some other rare cases, it is hard or long path to go with debugging. Specially with non boot-able system or only recovery shell available.

I will add some cases here:

- [Errors were encountered while processing Linux kernel packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858400/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-linux-kernel-packages)
- [Force removal of unwanted linux-image-extra* packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855755/force-removal-of-unwanted-linux-image-extra-packages)
- [Fixing a broken dpkg and apt package manger](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854153/fixing-a-broken-dpkg-and-apt-package-manger)

I have already used a dirty solution as explained my answer below. I would ask for a cleaner *workaround* to manually remove a kernel package as DPKG do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not a clean solution as it does not update the some generated kernel settings/files.(It skips all post-/pre- scripts & dpkg triggers)**

1. Check the installed files using

   ```
    dpkg -L linux-image-...
   ```
2. Remove them manually
3. Remove generated RAMDisk

   ```
   sudo rm /boot/initrd.img-...
   ```
4. Backup `/var/lib/dpkg/status` them open it and change its status to `deinstall`
5. Update grub menu

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Comment: At least one should delete the respective /boot/initrd.img-* file(s).